# Converting String to Android JSONObject loses utf-8

Tags: android, utf-8, json

I am trying to get a (JSON formatted) String from a URL and consume it as a Json object. I lose UTF-8 encoding when I convert the String to JSONObject.

This is The function I use to connect to the url and get the string:

```
private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content.toString();
}
```

When I get data from server, the following code displays correct characters:

```
String output = getUrlContents(url);
Log.i("message1", output);
```

But when I convert the output string to JSONObject the Persian characters becomes question marks like this ??????. (messages is the name of array in JSON)

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(output);
String messages = new String(reader.getString("messages").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
Log.i("message2", messages);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're telling Java to convert the string (with key `message`) to bytes using ISO-8859-1 and than to create a new String from these bytes, interpreted as UTF-8.

```
new String(reader.getString("messages").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

You could simply use:

```
String messages = reader.getString("messages");
```

Comment: This works because the bytes you're receiving over the wire are already interpreted correctly in `getUrlContents` and are internally stored as a UTF-16 string.

Comment: `getUrlContents ` only works when the server's character encoding matches the client's.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code as the following:

```
    private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return content.toString().trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got two encoding issues:

1. The server sends text encoded in a character set. When you setup your InputStreamReader, you need to pass the encoding the server used so it can be decoded properly. The character encoding is usually given in the `Content-type` HTTP response, in the `charset` field. JSON is typically UTF-8 encoded, but can also be legally UTF-16 and UTF-32, so you need to check. Without a specified encoding, your system environment will be used when marshalling bytes to Strings, and vice versa . Basically, you should always specify the charset.
2. `String messages = new String(reader.getString("messages").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");` is obviously going to cause issues (if you have non-ascii characters) - it's encoding the string to ISO-8995-1 and then trying to decode it as UTF-8.

A simple regex pattern can be used to extract the `charset` value from the Content-type header before reading the inputstream. I've also included a neat InputStream -> String converter.

```
private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        // Get charset field from Content-Type header
        String contentType = urlConnection.getContentType();
        // matches value in key / value pair
        Pattern encodingPattern = Pattern.compile(".*charset\\s*=\\s*([\\w-]+).*");
        Matcher encodingMatcher = encodingPattern.matcher(contentType);
        // set charsetString to match value if charset is given, else default to UTF-8
        String charsetString = encodingMatcher.matches() ? encodingMatcher.group(1) : "UTF-8";

        // Quick way to read from InputStream.
        // \A is a boundary match for beginning of the input
        return new Scanner(is, charsetString).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but you might be able to do something like this:

```
JSONObject result = null;
String str = null;
try 
{           
    str = new String(output, "UTF-8");
    result = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(str).nextValue();
} 
catch (Exception e) {}

String messages = result.getString("messages");
```