# Android Hindi Text Displaying special Characters

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I am making a language specific app in which user selects language from the list (either Hindi or English).

What happens is when user selects the English language ,everything works perfectly i.e user inserts the data into database and then retrieve it in the text fields properly but when user selects Hindi language and inserts data into database in Hindi language it displays text fields value as "??????"

I want is the text fields value must be displayed in Hindi language ..
 I have used Typeface for this but that does not work
This is my part of code

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hindi.ttf");                                        //i have put hindi.ttf file in fonts folder under assets under main
        name.setTypeface(tf);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.tvsave) {
                    if (name.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        name.setError("Name cannot be empty");
                    } else if (phone.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        phone.setError("Phone No. cannot be empty");
                    } 

    else if(!phone.getText().toString().matches(phonePattern)) 
                            phone.setError("Invalid Mobile");
                        } else if (house.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            house.setError("House No. cannot be empty");
                        } else if (area.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            area.setError("Area cannot be empty");
                        } else if (landmark.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            landmark.setError("Landmark cannot be empty");
                        } else if
                                (name.getText().toString().length() == 0 || phone.getText().toString().length() == 0 || house.getText().toString().length() == 0 || area.getText().toString().length() == 0 || landmark.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Details",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(AddNewAddress.this)) {
                            new saveaddress().execute(custid, name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString(), house.getText().toString(), landmark.getText().toString(), datamodel.getId(), area.getText().toString());                //this is saving data into database
                        } else {
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AddNewAddress.this);
                            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);

                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.internetconnectiondialog);
                            dialog.setTitle(AddNewAddress.this.getResources().getString(R.string.connectionfailed));
                            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
                            text.setText(AddNewAddress.this.getResources().getString(R.string.checkinternetsettings));
                            dialog.show();
                            Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
                            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spncity);
            new spinnercity().execute(language);

        }



class saveaddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialogFrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
            dialogFrag.setCancelable(false);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                String response = AddNewAddressPostHit.getJSONfromURL(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5], params[6]);

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                message = jsonObject.getString("Msg");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialogFrag.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
```

I want these `text_fields` value must be displayed in `Hindi` language  when user inserts the data into `Hindi` language else `English`
  I have used `Typeface` for this but that does not work.
 Tell me where I am wrong as soon as possible.

Comment: are you able to explicitly set hindi text in the field?

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: instead of from db.. if you setText  some hindi text. Otherwise it maybe some characterset issue elsewhere

Comment: I have set the Text in text field from the string value got from database

Comment: ok.. but if you hard code the text field?

Comment: then it displays it correctly

Comment: did @Ankush solution work? because the issue is not about displaying its either retrieval or storage. you will have to debug there

Comment: no that is also not working

Comment: I guess you will have to test your backend

Comment: i Have checked it through postman,,everything works correctly

Comment: @Neha try to read data on debug. Because while display data in textview can be changed but in debug this will display the actual data

Comment: @Neha postman what? Are you fetching data from server? If it is then the real problem is which i have answered below. This has to be handled at server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069799/android-json-charset-utf-8-problems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687466/converting-string-to-android-jsonobject-loses-utf-8

Comment: @Ankush at debug time also it is displaying ?

Comment: the text which you actually are expecting to display on your textview other than some random "???????" text

Answer (score 0):

try converting your string data with this while saving to db and same while fetching these from db.

```
String str = (URLDecoder.decode(your_editext_value, "UTF-8"));
```