# How to Set Character Encoding to UTF-8 for JSONObject in the Android

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8

i need to show text in a UTF-8 Character Encoding in the android App, Here is my Code for JSONAsyncTask in:

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Wait...");
        dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("news");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    News news = new News();

                    news.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
                    news.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                    news.setDate(object.getString("date"));
                    news.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                    newsList.add(news);
                }
                return true;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Of course, Before i'm Asking, research and see these result:

- [How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java)
- [Converting String to Android JSONObject loses utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687466/converting-string-to-android-jsonobject-loses-utf-8)
- [Encoding JSON to support UTF-8 characters in an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182680/encoding-json-to-support-utf-8-characters-in-an-android-app)
- [Android JSON CharSet UTF-8 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069799/android-json-charset-utf-8-problems)

and many more... But that answers can't solve my problem.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVn7X.png)

Comment: Why these result can help you to solve your problem ? Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: a still in my problem and character did not encoded to utf-8.

Comment: @FrédéricLetellier  Please See ScreenShot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated in 2021**

**JAVA**

Finally i'm solved my problem.

Final code:

```
 @Override
     protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

     try {
         HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

> **change status to:**

```
         if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
             
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

> **edit this code to:**

```
             String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HTTP.UTF_8);
             JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
             JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("news");
             for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                 News news = new News();

                 news.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
                 news.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                 news.setDate(object.getString("date"));
                 news.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                 newsList.add(news);
             }
             return true;
         }
     } catch (ParseException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return false;
 }
```

**Kotlin**

```
 fun doInBackground(vararg urls: String?): Boolean? {
    try {
        val httppost = HttpGet(urls[0])
        val httpclient: HttpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
        val response: HttpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost)
        val status: Int = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()

           if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                val entity: HttpEntity = response.getEntity()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply encode, decode the **Jsonobject** using **URLEncoder, URLDecoder**. The example is given below

1.Encode the **Jsonobject**

```
    try
    {
        String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(jsonobject, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("UTF 8",encoded );
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
    }
```

2.Decode the **Jsonobject**

```
    try
    {
      String   decoded = URLDecoder.decode(jsonobject, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("UTF 8",decoded );
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
    }
```

Comment: It's Not Working... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
String URL = your_URL;
URL obj = new URL(URL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes